# Bundle install is throwing error when installing coffee-script-source -v '1.6.3'

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4 but I'm getting an error with coffee-script when I generate new rails project

Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/build_info/coffee-script-source-1.6.3.info
An error occurred while installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.6.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Getting the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem. Run

```
sudo bundle update
```

inside your new site directory. Ruby will then have no trouble installing whatever packages it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue and came across your post when I googled it. I had to run:

- sudo gem install turbolinks -v '1.3.0'
- sudo gem install uglifier -v '2.2.1'
- sudo gem install multi_json -v '1.8.2'

before I could get the bundle install to complete. However, if you are reading the rails tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-rubygems), it says not to worry if that stage fails, as the railsgem file is updated and you manually run:

- bundle update
- bundle install

Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

do once: sudo rails new demo

and then for other projects just rails new project_name